# Native Android app and touch event update rate

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, juce

I am developing a native Android app using the JUCE C++ framework. The app is rendering using OpenGL. Non-interative animations perform very well.
However, interactive touch-responsive animations e.g. dragging a component are slow to update. It is not at all smooth. I measured on the Java side and its averaging around 70-80 ms or so between each ACTION_MOVE event.

> UPDATE:   I think the main issue may be to do with rendering whats
>   underneath the component being moved. When I tried out the JuceDemo,
>   using the Window demo I found I had bad performance dragging a window
>   over another, but if I drag the window around where there is only
>   empty space, it performs fine and feels smooth.

**Is there a way I can increase the animated UI responsiveness in my app?**

I've made some changes to the standard Java template provided by the Introjucer so that the native `handlePaint()` function is not called when there is an OpenGL context. (as suggested [here](http://www.juce.com/comment/305381#comment-305381))

Comment: Well, for one thing you could improve your devices CPU... But let's be serious: there could be lots of factors making this process lag, not the code. Post the code you are using into the question and start from there ~~ (and it's probably your alteration to the code that's causing it though...) Maybe the problem is that it appears laggy due to it not being rendered as often as you altered the code?

Comment: Which is you test device - a Samsung Galaxy Note? I'm using JUCE and on Samsung devices I know such performance issues too. Problem: onDraw() is called on each touch event for the whole UI size. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @monotomy the test device is Samsung Galaxy Ace 2. I also just tested on old HTC Desire and got some extreme graphical glitches when only doing OpenGL calls (disabled handlePaint in onDraw) but it gave me a clue that the whole screen is drawn each time. Need to investigate further..

Comment: Sorry for the lateness. You should make a request/report in the JUCE forum - as I know they are working on Android stuff in the moment.

Comment: @monotomy yes I am in contact with them, sent in a few fixes and improvements for Android over last few months. They told me they are looking into this issue soon - they have two new members of the team since I wrote this question :)